# Tight Single-Handle Moen Bathroom Faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet, bathroom-fixtures, stuck

I've got a single-handle Moen bathroom faucet (see picture) that has become very tight to turn left or right or push in and pull out.  It works, but it has a "stuck" feeling that it shouldn't have.  (I have another one in a different bathroom and it doesn't do this.)  I tried putting some WD-40 in the space where it turns, but it didn't do anything.  Does anyone have any suggestions on things to try to loosen it up?

Many thanks!

[image: bathroom faucet]

Comment: Probably, a washer needs replacing.  Open the top up and have a look.  Turn the water off first, in case

Comment: If it's in a private home, and you bought it, it's "guaranteed for life" so call (yes, make an old fashioned voice call, really, it's the best way) Moen and they will likely send you some parts. It's more likely to have a cartridge than washers, being a single-handle unit.